# Unable to update (first_or_initialize)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This has been driving me crazy. I use a first_or_initialize method on the user, and either it doesn't sign in correctly, or it won't let me update and save the user because it says it exists in the logs.

I'm connected with the twitter API, and I'm redirecting the user to a page called setups after their registration so that I can get their email address. For some reason it won't update this. Anyone has an idea why?

Sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  if user.persisted? && user.email?
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to campaigns_path, notice: "old user"
  elsif user.save || user.email.nil?
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to setup_users_path
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Unable to sign you in!'
  end
end
```

User model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
    user.provider             = auth.provider
    user.profile_image_url    = auth.info.image
    user.followers_count      = auth.followers_count
    user.uid                  = auth.uid
    user.access_token         = auth.credentials.token
    user.access_token_secret  = auth.credentials.secret
    user.name                 = auth.info.name
    user.nickname             = auth.info.nickname
    user.website              = auth.info.urls.website
    user.save!
  end
end
```

and the users/setup:

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>

<%= f.button "Here's mine", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Users_controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Successfully updated'
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Unable to update'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in development, I prefer the `!` symbol whenever I'm doing an update_attributes. This way, I will know if there are any validation errors happening.

Use `@user.update_attributes!(user_params)`  in your controller instead of `@user.update_attributes(user_params)` this way, you will see the corresponding errors.

If you are using Rails 4 or greater I hope you are having the `params.permit()` present.

If not, check out https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters for more info.